# Generate fmp4 chunks for HLS with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, fmp4

I am trying to generate fragmented MP4 as the chunks for HLS as introduced by apple last year.

See link -> https://bitmovin.com/hls-news-wwdc-2016/

Does ffmpeg supports this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of May 2018 with ffmpeg v4, this appears to be fixed (works for me at least):

```
ffmpeg -y -i udp://@:50000 -c copy -hls_segment_type fmp4 -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 10 -hls_flags delete_segments+append_list+split_by_time -hls_playlist_type event ~/Sites/foo/index_4000.m3u8
```

Comment: +1 I wonder if you know how to fix EXT-X-MAP:URI in m3u8 when specifying absolute hls_fmp4_init_filename using ffmpeg? https://stackoverflow.com/q/60460212/470749 Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As of March 2017, it appears not. [Ticket 5699 in the FFmpeg Trac](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5699) is a request for fMP4 segments in HLS output, currently tagged, "new/enhancement."

Comment: Ye, I saw that too, that means we'll have to wait then?