# How to fix EXT-X-MAP:URI in m3u8 when specifying absolute hls_fmp4_init_filename using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, http-live-streaming, ffmpeg-php, fmp4

Today I found [this blog post](https://hlsbook.net/hls-fragmented-mp4/) teaching me about fragmented mp4s (fmp4s).

Using [the ffmpeg docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Options-5), I've made great progress.

I run this:

```
'/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/myproject/storage/app/sample_media/2020-02-27/Sample Videos 5.mp4' \
'-c:v' 'libx264' '-s:v' '1920x1080' \
 '-crf' '20' '-sc_threshold' '0' '-g' '48' '-keyint_min' '48' \
'-hls_list_size' '0' '-hls_time' '10' '-hls_allow_cache' '0' '-b:v' '4889k' \
'-maxrate' '5866k' '-hls_segment_type' 'fmp4' \
'-hls_fmp4_init_filename' '/myproject/public/storage/000000002/init.mp4' \
'-hls_segment_filename' '/myproject/public/storage/000000002/list_1080p_%04d.m4s' \
'-hls_key_info_file' '/myproject/hls_hls.keyInfo' '-strict' '-2' '-threads' '12' \
'/myproject/public/storage/000000002/list_1080p.m3u8'
```

And then I use [hls.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/) on my webpage to try to show the video.

Initially, it won't load.

But then I can get the video to load properly if I refresh the page after making this edit to list_1080p.m3u8:

Change from:

`#EXT-X-MAP:URI="/myproject/public/storage/000000002/init.mp4"`

To:

`#EXT-X-MAP:URI="init.mp4"`

**How can I change my ffmpeg command so that it knows the absolute path of where to save the init.mp4 but also knows to write in the m3u8 only the filename `init.mp4` without any path?**

(I've tried using `-hls_fmp4_init_filename init.mp4` without the abosolute path, but then it creates the init.mp4 at the root, which also doesn't work. I need each video's init.mp4 to be in its own folder.)

Comment: I think https://superuser.com/q/1529459/74576 might be the problem.

Comment: No, but I'll update here if I ever get back to this project.